# Separation plot analysis with r

Tags: r, plot, statistics, logistic-regression

I don't quite get how to use separation plot to see if a model is a good fit, can someone help me understand it? Here is an example I'm working with:

[image: separation plot]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the plot you generated was created using [separationplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/separationplot/) package.

Documentation of this package doesn't explain well how to interpret the plots, but the package authors released a paper that explains how to use and interpret separation plots.

You should start with reading this paper by [Greenhill et al., 2011](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-5907.2011.00525.x) (open version is [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228213305/download)).